# How to configure Felix OBR repositories list?

Tags: repository, osgi, apache-felix, obr

Is there any way to specify a number of OBR repositories in Felix's `config.properties` file? I do can add a repository at runtime, but I have to do it after restart.

"Prefrences Service" does not help, it seems "Bundle Repository" does not use it.

Comment: Actually even ServiceMix (built on top of Felix) does not remember updated OBR list after restart.

Answer (score 4):

conf/config.properties

obr.repository.url=(space delimited list of urls)

Comment: I really wonder why it is so hard to find this information in the documentation, e.g. at felix.apache.org... btw, it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is :

- Set a default repository(Felix property). I don't think that you can use commas but you could try.
- Add a list of repositories at runtime(You could store them in a db and repopulate/register the list dynamically at each startup). If you just need to query the *repository service* and update the *repository list* in an activator for example.